# Convert an object into string using ToString() method , the string can not serve as a variable?

Tags: c#

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.ToString() = Regex.Replace(sb.ToString(),"something","something");
```

There is an error with the left hand side term: sb.Tostring().

Comment: `ToString()` is a method, not property.

Comment: ToString() is a method, not a property. You can't assign values to it. Also, it does not convert the object to a string, it returns a string representing the object.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, specifically `StringBuilder.ToString()` will actually return the *string* built by that `StringBuilder` instance.

Comment: @CoolBots but still this is a string representation of the instance, **not** a conversion of it.

Answer (score 1):

`ToString()` is a method, and cannot be assigned to. Change your code to:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//...do something with your StringBuilder...

var result = Regex.Replace(sb.ToString(),"something","something");
```

Note, your code creates a `StringBuilder`, and ... does not do anything with it. In your case, `sb.ToString()` will produce an empty string; so `result` will also be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the content of a `StringBuilder` you can't assign to the result of a function<sup>1</sup> as a function return is not assignable.

Use

```
var x = sb.ToString();
sb.Clear();
sb.Append(Regex.Replace(x, "something", "something"));
```

---

<sup>1</sup> C# 7 reference returns do allow this (but only after assigning to a local `ref` variable), but the function needs to be written for that purpose.